# How can I show an empty WooCommerce cart?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, hooks

I've made a single-page checkout template for donations. The donation plugin is attached to the cart and will update the cart properly, however the cart will not display on my page if 0 items are in the basket when the user arrives. The intended end user will generally have no items in their cart.

How can I force the WooCommerce cart to show up if there are no products in the cart?

Comment: For any trying to answer; what is needed is to cause `WC_Cart::is_empty()` to `return false` on you custom template or page. Seems the action `woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session` may be the best place to trick the logic. I solved my current problem by changing the is_empty() function directly - which is a wrong solution. ---  `function is_empty(){ global $wp; $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request)); if($current_url==$CheckoutURL) return false; return 0 === sizeof( $this->get_cart() ); }` As you may note, sizeof($this->get_cart()) is ultimately the deciding factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global $woocommerce;
$count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;`

This should be the variable you'd want to work with. Try `var_dump` on this to display its value.

Comment: I tried `add_filter('template_include', 'cart_setup');` and manually setting the count + putting a blank object in the cart_contents array if using my checkout template, but no luck changing behavior.

Comment: turns out WC doesn't check `cart_contents_count` for `is_empty()` function. It does `sizeof( $this->get_cart() )`. And `get_cart()` will check for wp_loaded, then check if the cart has been got from session and grab it if not, finally it just returns `array_filter( (array) $this->cart_contents )` the step where it grabs cart from session sometimes. at the end of grabbing the cart the action `woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session` is called. if cart is in the right state immediately after this call, it may be tricked. i didn't figure out that state so i cheated and changed is_empty()